# Is $ S_n$ is uniformly convergent ? Yes/NO

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Is  $\displaystyle S_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \sin\frac{1}{3^nx}$   uniformly convergent on the interval   $[1, \infty)$ ?  True /false

My attempt : NO, the  given series  will not uniformly convergent  on  $[1, \infty)$ because the cauchy sequence  criterion for  uniform convergence fail

That is $$\vert S_{n +m}(x) - S_n(x) |= 2^{n+1} \sin \frac{1}{3^{n+1}x} + ....... + 2^{n+m} \sin \frac{1}{3^{n+m}x} \ge  2^{n+1} \frac{2}{ \pi}  \frac{1}{3^{n+1} x} +....... + 2^{n+m}\frac{2}{\pi} \frac{1}{3^{n+m}x} \ge \frac{2^{n+1} {2}}{\pi3^{n+1} x}$$

Is this  true  ?

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Your calculation looks correct, however the conclusion you draw is wrong. You show that $|S_{n+m}-S_n|$ is greater than something that goes to zero when $n\to\infty$. This tells you nothing about if the Cauchy criterion fails or not.

Comment: @Winther if put  $x=  1/ 3^n$ then its  fail

Comment: But $x=1/3^n$ is not in $[1,\infty)$ right?

Comment: Ya  u r  right @Winther thanks  gots it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True. The main idea is that $\sin x \leq x$ for $x\geq 0.$ Hence, on the domain $[1,\infty),$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \sin\left(\frac{1}{3^n x}\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \left(\frac{1}{3^n x}\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n,
$$
which is obviously convergent as a geometric series.

Comment: thanks @ZuhZug  but   im not getting  how   u directly writes   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \left(\frac{1}{3^n x}\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n?$

Comment: Fix $2^n.$ The fraction $\frac{1}{3^n x}$ is maximized when $x=1.$ This is true for all $n$ so the inequality holds for the sum.